# JsonArray to Realm with gson

Tags: java, android, json, gson, realm

I have a problem to store an jsonarray to realm
I get a Exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY
```

oncreat activity i do this

```
Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();

    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration); // Make this Realm the default;
    realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
```

but the realm variable is null

my saving code is

```
adressModelListrealm = gson.fromJson(parentArray, AdressModelRealm.class);
```

when i try to store with new code

```
List<AdressModelRealm> woList = gson.fromJson(parentArray, new TypeToken<List<AdressModelRealm>>() {
                    }.getType());
                    realm.beginTransaction();
                    realm.copyToRealm(woList);
                    realm.commitTransaction();
```

i get a nullPointexecption

my Model:

```
public class AdressModelRealm extends RealmObject {




private String SNR;
private String ADR_2_8;     // Adressnummer
private String ADR_20_30;   // Adressname
```

...many more with getter an setter

and my json array :

```
 [{
    "SNR": "6",
    "ADR_2_8": "10000",
    "ADR_20_30": "Kunde Inland",
    "ADR_2332_20": "+49 (1234) 56789-00",
    "ADR_242_20": "+49 (1234) 56789-99",
    "ADR_2187_46": "Inlandstraße",
    "ADR_2170_11": "1",
    "ADR_110_10": "12345",
    "ADR_2233_40": "Inlandsort",
    "ADR_1330_60": "inlandzk@meine-firma-homepage.de"
 }]
```

Can me help anyone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to want to use [JSON Schema to POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) so that you can convert your objects from JSON to Java objects. Then you're going to want to have `AddressModel extend RealmObject` so that you can put your Java objects into realm like so

```
Realm.init();
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                    @Override
                    public void execute(Realm realm) {
                       realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(new AddressModel(//constructor);
                    }
                });
```

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Consuming-APIs-with-Retrofit) is a good tutorial on how JSONSchemaToPOJO works.

Comment: i have do that, but i get the same error, is ther an problem that the json is an array ? And i do that in an Async task, with adressModelListrealm = gson.fromJson(parentArray, AdressModelRealm.class); and than to realm with realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
       @Override
       public void execute(Realm realm) {
        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(woList);
       }
      });